# Can I put this formula in VBA so it returns the upcoming Tuesdays date in my header

Tags: vba

"IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY()),TODAY()+8-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+2,TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+3)"

OK sorry updating my question to be clearer. This is for VBA in excel. I need to put some type of code in there (my formula above doesn't seem to be correct either). Formula should calculate the upcoming Tuesday. If today is Tuesday then use today's date and if not give me the next upcoming Tuesday's date. I also need this to be my page header when I print the excel sheet.

Comment: What is the `WEEKDAY(TODAY())*2` doing? Why `*2`?

Comment: What's your definition of "upcoming Tuesday'? If today is Tuesday what day should it give? Today or the following Tuesday?

Comment: Your current formula gives `2023/07/18` when today is `2023/07/09`. You need to be very clear about what you want.

Comment: Are you sure this is VB.NET question? Maybe it is, but talking about VB in Excel makes it sound like it could be VBA. If it is VB.NET the of course you can't use that formula, but you can use the same logic, if that's appropriate. That's what you need to actually think about - logic - rather than code. If you understand the logic required then you can implement it in any language you want.

Comment: Here is my formula that computes the next Tuesday, assuming that if today is Tuesday then you want the next one: `=TODAY()+7-MOD(WEEKDAY(TODAY())-3,7)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Weekday](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/weekday-function) to get a whole number representing the day of the week and [Now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/now-function) to get the current date. Using a simple Do While loop, increment a Date variable until Weekday returns 3.

**VBA/VB6**

```
Dim currentDate As Date

currentDate = Now

Do While Weekday(currentDate) <> 3
    currentDate = currentDate + 1
Loop

MsgBox "Upcoming Tuesday is " & Format(currentDate, "dddd, mmm d yyyy")
```

**VB.NET**

```
Dim currentDate As Date

currentDate = Now

Do While Weekday(currentDate) <> 3
    currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(1)
Loop

MsgBox("Upcoming Tuesday is " & currentDate.ToShortDateString)
```

Comment: That's not valid VB.NET code. VB6 or VBA maybe. That said I'm not completely convinced that the OP is using VB.NET anyway.

Comment: @jmcilhinney updated answer with VB.NET code

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this in VB.NET then here are two very similar ways to get the date of the "next" Tuesday. The first option will give you today's date if today is Tuesday:

```vb
Dim todaysDate = Date.Today

Do Until todaysDate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Tuesday
    todaysDate = todaysDate.AddDays(1)
Loop
```

The second option will give you the date of Tuesday next week if today is Tuesday:

```vb
Dim todaysDate = Date.Today

Do
    todaysDate = todaysDate.AddDays(1)
Loop Until todaysDate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Tuesday
```

It is better to use the `DayOfWeek` enumeration as it is self-documenting.